# Keep Session Alive sitecore mvc

Tags: session, server-side, keep-alive

I have a scenario where session is getting expired after some time of inactivity, But I need to keep session alive for some more time, need to handle this from server side. Any help or input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Purpose of keepalive.aspx**
Here's the full code of the page in Sitecore 8.0

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
  <title>Keep Alive</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    Keep Alive Page
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you can read more here : https://sitecorestuff.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/how-to-keep-alive-your-sitecore-instance-24x7/